# phpMyAdmin Behaving Badly with user defined variables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is just to report some bad behavior the SQL query panel in phpMyAdmin (phpMyAdmin 4.0.10.14).

I have a User table with three records. IDs are 2,3 and 4.
I ran this:

```
SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) FROM User;
```

and got this:

```
@IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id)
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4
```

Clearly the select actually ran twice silently before running a third time to prepare the result set. Each time it ran it accumulated the IDs in @IDS. I initialised @IDS with 'xxx' just to make that all the IDs were coming from the one query. I have seen other problems with numerical user defined getting strange values, but could not pin it down. This test makes it clearer that there's a problem.

But it gets odder. I ran this:

```
SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT ids INTO @RESULT FROM
(SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) as ids FROM User limit 1) AS HG;
SELECT @RESULT;

SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) as ids FROM User;
```

and got this:

```
@RESULT
xxx 2

ids 
xxx 2 3 4 2
xxx 2 3 4 2 3
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4
```

Then I ran this

```
SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) as ids FROM User;

SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT ids INTO @RESULT FROM
(SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) as ids FROM User limit 1) AS HG;
SELECT @RESULT;
```

and got

```
ids
xxx 2 2 3 4 2
xxx 2 2 3 4 2 3
xxx 2 2 3 4 2 3 4

@RESULT 
xxx 2
```

Then this

```
SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) FROM User;

SET @IDS = 'xxx';
SELECT @IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id) as ids FROM User;
```

gave me

```
@IDS := CONCAT(@IDS," ",id)
xxx 2 3 4 2
xxx 2 3 4 2 3
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4

ids 
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3
xxx 2 3 4 2 3 4 2 3 4
```

The moral: don't use user defined vars in this environment.

Comment: The moral rather should be: Use up to date software, it all works just fine in phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.

Comment: @Michal Čihař, that's a fair comment. And thanks for taking the time to explore the problem. Unfortunately I am working on my client's hosting environment, which is running 4.0.10.14.  As a freelance programmer I take what environment I am given.